# Jquery Show/hide extra rows with Datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

This problem requires something of a lengthy explanation. I am using the following code to allow the user to add/remove rows on a UI:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//group add limit
    var maxGroup = 12;

//add more fields group
    $(".addMore").click(function(){
     if($('body').find('.fieldGroup').length < maxGroup){
            var fieldHTML = '<div class="form-group fieldGroup">'+$(".fieldGroupCopy").html()+'</div>';
            $('body').find('.fieldGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);
        }else{
           alert('Maximum '+maxGroup+' groups are allowed.');
        }
    });

//remove fields group
    $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
      $(this).parents(".fieldGroup").remove();
    });
});
```

The initial input fields that are initially visible are in one part of the page:

```
<div class="form-group fieldGroup">
    <div class="input-group">
<!--INPUT FIELDS GO HERE--!>
    </div>
</div>
```

...and the 'copies', which appear when the user adds a 'row' to the UI are in another:

```
<div class="form-group fieldGroupCopy" style="display: none;">
    <div class="input-group">
<!--COPIED INPUT FIELDS GO HERE--!>
    </div>
</div>
```

All of this is contained within a single `form`, as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="add-event_submit.php">
<!--fieldGroup AND fieldGroupCopy elements--!>
</form>
```

For the most part, this works just fine. However, within each row I have a `datepicker`.

The **initial** datepicker is as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="date[]" id="datepicker1" value="DATE" style="width:102px; text-align:center" date-format="dd-mm-yyyy"></input>
```

The datepicker to be shown **in subsequent rows** is:

```
<input type="text" name="date[]" id="datepicker2" value="DATE" style="width:102px; text-align:center" date-format="dd-mm-yyyy"></input>
```

So, the show/hide function seems to be causing all sorts of problems with the datepicker. For example, the `style="display: none;` in `fieldGroupCopy` stops the second and any subsequent datepickers from showing. The input field is there, but clicking on it does nothing, because the `datepicker` popup remains hidden.

I was hoping therefore that the jquery code could be modified in order to remedy this.